# Move and rename folders php

Tags: php, rename, explode

I'm working with a script where i want to move folders to another directory,and give the folders new name.
I think i need to explode a string? But i don't get it to work properly.
Example i want the folder with original name: 351437-367628 and to have new name: from start to the hyphen.

I'm moving the folder by the glob and rename function.

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('folders')) {
        while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
            $newName = str_replace("-#","",$fileName);
            rename($fileName, $newName);
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can use [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

Comment: Please provide an example that shows the exact before and after of a string that you would like

Comment: i have to folders: input, and output. The input folder is droping folders with

Comment: pictures. the names could be 321321-6546541-54654, 654654-45-45646 654651-6544. Iwant to keep the name to the first hyphen so the folder is called 321321, 654654 and 654651

Comment: how can i keep the name only to the first hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode()` function as

```
$fileName = '351437-367628';
$newNametemp = explode("-",$fileName);
if(is_array($newNametemp)){
    $newName = $newNametemp[0];
    print_r($newName); // will return 351437,i.e. new name from start to hyphen
    rename($fileName, $newName);
}
```

To get all directories

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('path');
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDir() && !$fileInfo->isDot()) {
        $fileName = $fileInfo->getFilename();
        $newNametemp = explode("-",$fileName);
        if(is_array($newNametemp)){
            $newName = $newNametemp[0];
            print_r($newName); 
            rename($fileName, $newName);
        }
    }
}
```

if you are using a lower version of PHP try

```
if ($handle = opendir('path')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        if(is_dir($fileName) && ($fileName != '..' && $fileName != '.')){
            $newNametemp = explode("_",$fileName);
            if(is_array($newNametemp)){
                $newName = $newNametemp[0];
                print_r($newName); 
                echo "<br/>";
                rename($fileName, $newName);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: How can i get the $filename to be all folders?

Comment: i dont get this last one to work @deepika.  trying to use: $fileName = '/folder/output';    $newNametemp = explode("-",$fileName);
if(is_array($newNametemp)){
    $newName = $newNametemp[0];
    print_r($newName); // will return 351437,i.e. new name from start to hyphen
    rename($fileName, $newName);
}